# Getting extra and cite properties using acro

Tags: acronyms, acro

I'm using the `acro` package to manage a list of abbreviations. I have specified `extra` and `cite` values for some of these. Is there a simple way of using these in the text in the same way as `\acl` for the `long` property, and so on?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easily possible to define suitable commands for this completely analogous to the existing commands, see section 11 of the current manual (v2.7c). One command you need, `\acro_cite:n` unfortunately is not documented, yet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{foo}{
  short = xx,
  long  = description,
  extra = bla ,
  cite  = yy
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewAcroCommand \acextra { \acro_extra:n {#1} }
\NewAcroCommand \accite
  {
    \keys_set:nn {acro} { cite-connect = }
    \acro_cite:n {#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ac{foo} \par
\acextra{foo} \par
\accite{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]